# How to use border-style to make a right arrow

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h89xmbn5/1/

Html:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <span>First Name</span>
    <input type="text" required>
</form>
```

How can I make the arrow point right, instead of left for the span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
.form-wrapper span:after {
    border-width: 8px 0 8px 8px;
    border-style: solid none solid solid;
}
```

Instead:

```
.form-wrapper span:after {
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/h89xmbn5/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this works so far :)

Comment: @SiKni8 Maybe this is a good solution for you: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/h89xmbn5/5/. Note the commented lines to see what I have changed :)

Comment: If the SPAN expands a lot it doesn't auto fit. But for the purpose of the question, it's correct. Thank you.